# The need to pass different types in the initialization_list

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm looking for a template based way to pass arbitrary number of params in the initialization_list(s).

Something like:

```
func({0, 1}, {0, 2.0f}, {0, "boo"}, ...);
```

or

```
func({{0, 1}, {0, 2.0f}, {0, "boo", ...}});
```

In the same time I want to be able to check the type of the second param in each (inner) brace. Maybe get `sizeof(T)` maybe do some `if constexpr(std::is_same<T, ...>::value)` match.

Is it possible? If so how would `func()` definition look like?

Comment: The inner braces always have 2 elements?

Comment: `std::initializer_list<T>`, where `T` is a type with overloaded constructors?

Comment: @cigien yes, basically an index and a value

Comment: Figuring out the types is not hard necessarily. What do you want to do with all those types inside `func`?

Comment: My plan is to copy the memory occupied by a variables of arbitrary types into some opaque memory region. The type info is required to get sizeof(T) to pass the size to memcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `f` take `std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::any, std::any> >`:

```
void f(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::any, std::any> > il) {
    for (auto it = il.begin(); it != il.end(); ++it) {
        const std::type_info& type1 = it->first.type();
        const std::type_info& type2 = it->second.type();
        if (type1 == typeid(int)) {
            int val1 = std::any_cast<int>(it->first);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you have only a couple possible types, you can use `std::variant<int, float, /*e.g.; etc. */>` instead of `std::any`.

Comment: `Variant` is probably the better option. When you have a function that can eat totally arbitrary amounts of totally arbitrary types, you probably have a design problem. Whatever's at the back end consuming all those arguments is going to be complicated and vulnerable to bad inputs. Back to the old days of `varargs` functions.

Comment: @user4581301 Except that std::any throws an exception if you try to access it with the wrong type, so the objects inside can at most be copied around if their types are not handled explicitly. Not like varargs functions.

Comment: Agreed. I needed "Almost back to the old days" up there.